# I failed to stop propeller ads from my website

Tags: web, ads

I have configured propeller ads on my website, was hoping that it is a good way of making money, unfortunatly the popup generated are annoying my website visitor. I have decided to stop the ads, i have uninstalled plugin, i have deleted codes in the Header of my website, whenever you click there is a new popup opened, or an other new tab, and because of this some tools are listing my website under risky website.

My website is http://mucuruzi.com

can someone help me to know how i can completely remove this service of propeller ads from my website?

Thanks

UKURI